# 从。。。看 , 是。。。的 and 方面 in this sentence

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence from my textbook that is very confusing to me.

您看看这个，不管从价格方面看，还是从质量上看，都是值得考虑的。

First I understand it's meant to mean along the lines of: "Look at this one, not only in respect to price but also quality, it is worth considering."

If anyone could help breaking it down. I have some questions,

My first question is what does 从。。。看 mean?

Second: are (在)。。。方面 and (在)。。。上 the same?

Lastly what is 是。。。的 at the end? I think the 的 being used at the end modally to express certainty but then what is 是? I didn't think it was used like this with verbs/adjectives.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

从。。。看, 
means 
Inspect this thing from xxx side. 
(在)。。。方面,  (在)。。。上  
They are different expression of same meaning as the above.

都 是 值得 考虑 的。
is short for
(价格) (和) (质量) 都 是 值得 考虑 的 (因素)。
the "是" means "are".
Both price and quality are worth considering aspects.
can be shorted as
Both are worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

- "从"价格方面"看", 还是"从"质量上"看" - **looking from** the side of price or **looking from/on** the side/aspect of quality...
- "在价格方面"看", 还是"在"质量上"看" - **looking at/on** the side/aspect of price, or **looking at/on** the side/aspect of quality...
- "都是"值得"考虑的" - "both are" worth "to be considered"

Answer (score 0):

For the last question:

> 都----是----值得考虑的。

> Both----are----considerable.